# ContentValues put method

Tags: android, android-intent

At the db side, `checkInTime` and `checkOutTime` are of type `TIMESTAMP`

In my java code also, `checkInTime` and `checkOutTime` are of type `java.sql.Timestamp`

For inserting a record into db, i am using this piece of code:

```
1. ContentValues contentValues=new ContentValues();

    2. contentValues.put(USER_ID, userId);
    3. contentValues.put(ROOM_ID, roomId);
    4. contentValues.put(CHECK_IN, checkInTime);
    5. contentValues.put(CHECK_OUT, checkOutTime);

    6. return database.insert(MRM_BOOKING_DETAILS_TABLE, null, contentValues);
```

But i am getting compilation errors at line 4 and 5 since they are not expecting something of type java.sql.Timestamp

I can't see any put method of C`ontentValues` which will accept type `java.sql.Timestamp` in its second parameter. Please suggest how to pass the `java.sql.Timestamp` in such a case so that i can remove the compilation errors as well.

Thanks,

Comment: what data type is checkInTime and CheckOuttime

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I would suggest you to use `DATETIME` instead of `TIMESTAMP`. Its more general when handling dates and times.

Moreover, you can use SimpleDateFormat to parse DATETIME values when inserting or reading from database.

```
final SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
```

---

**Updated:**

Try doing it as below:

```
final SimpleDateFormat parser = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ss.SSS");

contentValues.put(CHECK_IN, parser.format(checkInTime));
contentValues.put(CHECK_OUT, parser.format(checkOutTime));
```

Comment: hi,
I cant change the datatype according to my wish, i have to go with what i am given as the requirement.

Can you please suggest me like how to insert record with java.sql.Timestamp ?

Comment: ok, see my updated answer. try the new date parser which i hope will help you to convert TimeStamp into sqlite's string format

Answer (score 0):

If checkInTime and checkOutTime are bith time stamps then before storing thm to contentvalue just convert to milliseconds and store them and while retriving reconvert then them to your required format. because ContentValue dont accept timeStamps so just convert and store so that you wont get any compliation error.